# Mixing macro-DO-loops with data step DO-loops

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Some context:

I have a string of digits (not ordered, but with known range 1 - 78) and I want to extract the digits to create specific variables with it, so I have

```
"64,2,3" => var_64 = 1; var_02 = 2; var_03 = 1; (the rest, like var_01 are all set to missing)
```

I basically came up with two solutions, one is using a `macro DO loop` and the other one a `data step DO loop`. The non-macro solution was to fist initialize all variables `var_01 - var_78` (via a macro), then to put them into an array and then to gradually set the values of this array while looping through the string, word-by-word.

I then realized that it would be way easier to use the loop iterator as a macro variable and I came up with this **MWE**:

```
%macro fast(w,l);
do p = 1 to &l.;
    %do j = 1 %to 9;
        if &j. =  scan(&w.,p,",") then var_0&j. = 1 ;
    %end;
    %do j = 10 %to 78;
        if &j. =  scan(&w.,p,",") then var_&j. = 1 ;
    %end;
end;
%mend;

data want;
string = "2,4,64,54,1,4,7";
l = countw(string,",");
%fast(string,l);
run;
```

It works (no errors, no warnings, expected result) but I am unsure about mixing `macro-DO-loops` and `non-macro-DO-loops`. Could this lead to any inconsistencies or should I just stay with the non-macro solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is comparing numbers like 1 to strings like "1".

```
&j. =  scan(&w.,p,",")
```

It will work as long as the strings can be converted into numbers, but it is not a good practice.  It would be better to explicitly convert the strings into numbers.

```
input(scan(&w.,p,","),32.)
```

You can do what you want with an array. Use the number generated from the next item in the list as the index into the array.

```
data want;
  string = "2,4,64,54,1,4,7";
  array var_ var_01-var_78 ;
  do index=1 to countw(string,",");
     var_[input(scan(string,index,","),32.)]=1;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! Your array solution is pretty close to mine, except why can we define arrays without specifying their length? About the mixing of data step and macro DO-loop, any advice? Actually I was wondering that this was working at all...

Comment: You do not need to tell SAS the number of elements in the array when you have listed them in the statement. It can count.  As to mixing %DO and DO it is fine, just be clear what is happening.  Use the MPRINT option to help as you can then see the actual SAS code the %DO loop generated.

Comment: Excellent tip to use the mprint option! Got it now. About the length, I've never seen any mention of not stating it...I usually used the {*} but apparently this is default, thx again.